# How to implement "find or create" with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Currently I'm hitting a wall with Ember Data loading some data which might exist or might not. If a record does not exist, the web application should create it.

Simple use case: documenting an inventory. If an article does not exist, a new article should be added. If it does exist, then the employee can immediately use the information.

I suspect the adapter find() method to be the source of this problem. It cannot handle a 404 not found error and passing an empty result does not work either.

Probably I am overlooking something trivial, as 'find or create' is quite a regular pattern. Please help...

Comment: I'm stuck here too. I'm trying to do this inside a route, it seems that once findRecord fails I get stuck in .catch() with no way to create a record or return it. @peter , any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

See [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1523), or here's the solution:

```
findOrCreate: (type, properties)->
  @store.find(type, properties.id).then null, (reason)=>
    if reason.status == 404
      record = @store.recordForId(type, properties.id)
      record.loadedData()
      record.setProperties(properties)
      record.save()
    else
      throw reason
```

Answer (score 1):

see [#296](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/296)
Already a bug report for this

Comment: Thanks, it appears this is one of the topics which need some more love.